# Check numerical solution to constraint optimization

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

I want to optimize a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ subject to $x_1\geq0$ and $x_1+x_2\geq0$. I know $f$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$ in closed-form but as they are nasty, I use a computer to numerically solve the problem yielding $(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)$.

- Will the numerical solution still (approximately) satisfy the two partial derivatives, i.e. $\frac{\partial f(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)}{\partial x_1}\approx0$ and $\frac{\partial f(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)}{\partial x_2}\approx0$?
- If not, is there another equation which the numerical solution should (come close to) satisfy that takes the constraints into account?

Comment: Why solve for the critical points and not just do gradient descent? Knowing the derivatives makes the gradient calculation trivial.

Comment: @David at the moment, I just use a minimizer on $f$. That's more than fine to me. I just want to check how good the approximation is. Normally (if there are no constraints), I'd plug the numbers into the partial derivatives and zero whether I am close to zero but I am doubtful that this works if there are constraints.

Comment: I don't know what you can learn in general from knowing the derivatives at your maximum. If a gradient descent/ascent terminates it means the derivatives are small already. If the optimum is on one of the constraints then the gradient vector should perpendicular to the constraint curve. Maybe I misunderstand your goal.

Comment: @David My goal is that when the computer comes up with $x_1\approx 0.8738$ and $x_2\approx -3.847$. (I making these numbers completely up), I can then check, whether this is _really_ an optimum. For unconstrained optimization of functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, I'd simply plug in the approximation into the derivative and see whether I am close to zero. If so, then this is a good sign. I'd like to know whether I can find such an equation for the setting in my question. Is there an equation the optimal values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ ought to satisfy given the two constraints in the question?

Comment: For unconstrained problems, if a point is a local optimum then its first partial derivatives have to be zero. For constrained problems, its derivatives have to be zero or it's a boundary point of your domain. In this case, $(0,x_2)$, when $x_2 \geq 0$ or $(x_1, -x_1)$ for $x_1 \geq 0$ would be the boundary points. Remember that these are necessary conditions and not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the optimal point is on the interior of the feasible set (and not on a boundary) then the the partial derivatives at the optimal point will be approximately equal to 0.

If the optimal point is on the boundary, then it is very likely that the partial derivatives won't equal 0.  (There's no reason why they should.)

If $f$ is not convex and you use a method like gradient descent (or one of its many descendants), you are only guaranteed to approximate a locally optimal point rather than a globally optimal point

Comment: On the boundary the equivalent condition to (approximately) zero partial derivatives is that the gradient vector should be (approximately) perpendicular to the boundary.